# Accessing a MS Access DB from c# windows forms in an intranet scenario

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, intranet

i've developped a windows forms application with VS2012/C# and i'm planning to install in a file share server, so the application can be installed in different pc and access database.

when i developped the application, i've used this connection string :

```
OleDbConnection connectionString = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|mydb.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
```

now my question is clear, will this connection string be available for the scenario below ( intranet ) if so, how to implement it ? i mean just put the db in the server and install the windows forms application in the pc or will i need to change the connection string.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `|DataDirectory|` portion of your string.

`DataDirectory` points to your local data directory.  As Access is a file based database, you should be able to change this [to point directly to the share or mapped directory](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/network-location/).

Be aware that upon connecting to the database, Access creates an [LDB file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208778) that holds the user connection information and locks the database.  If your users dont have write access to the share, the connection will fail.

Comment: What will be the new connection string for accessing db in intranet ? thank you

Comment: @user2233979, I was just getting to that.  I added a link to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/network-location/

Comment: thank you! one last question! do i need to change the name of the server/share/folder or just the name of the database ?

Comment: @user2233979, I dont understand that question.  You just put the file on a share, then change the path in the `Data Source` section of your query string to match.

Comment: my question was about this connection string your provides me Data Source=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.accdb; what server\share\folder\ for do i need to modify them or just the name of the db ?

Comment: @user2233979, So you dont know what your path will be? When you put the file on the network it will have a path on your network.  If you put the file on a server called `MyNetworkServer` on its `c:\shareddirectory` directory, then share that directory as `myShare`, your path would be `\\MyNetworkServer\myShare\myAccessDb.mdb`  Does that make sense?